# Adding an Album to the Android Photo Gallery (in code)

Tags: android

I would like to be able to create an Android app that adds additional photo albums to the default android photo gallery. The content of these albums would be remote, similar to how the Picasa albums are handled. I have looked into the media scanner and it seems to not handle remote content and I have not been able to find any reference for the gallery itself or any other means of providing additional photo albums.

I have done some searching on the android developers site, here and general Googling and have come up short... does anyone have any suggestions about how this can be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the android stock gallery, this is what ive  found out:

The android albums are not actually albums, but folders.
You justo need to create a folder with the name you want the album to show and there must be at least one  picture in it.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of providing a gallery based on a remote set of images, rather than located on the device itself.